# Datatables footer error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'nTf' of undefined

Tags: php, jquery, datatable, datatables, php-5.4

I am facing problem related to datatables. I have a large number of records (45,000 +). So I am using datatables with "Server Side " coding.

The issue is this, its showing the following error in the below code is:

ERROR:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'nTf' of undefined

```
// allows cells to be used for multiple columns using colspan
    if ( tfoot !== null ) {
        var cells = oSettings.aoFooter[0];

        for ( i=0, ien=cells.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
            column = columns[i];
            column.nTf = cells[i].cell;


            if ( column.sClass ) {
                $(column.nTf).addClass( column.sClass );
            }
```

JavaScript code I am using for this is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#authorsdatatab').dataTable( {
        "bPaginate": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,     
        "sAjaxSource": "../assets/common/authorsServerSide.php",
});
  });
```

The data I am using for showing column in server side scripting is:

```
$aColumns = array( 'a_ID', 'a_name', 'a_birth', 'a_death' );

/* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
$sIndexColumn = "a_ID";

/* DB table to use */
$sTable = "authors";
```

Comment: column is defined and having some value here `column = columns[i];            column.nTf = cells[i].cell;` so what is this `nTF` you are trying to access???

Comment: #Feroz I have no idea aboyt nTF so can you tell me how i can check i am using right nTF plzzz..???

Comment: If you have no idea about `nTf` why are you using it? Do you understand what to code is doing?

Comment: @markpYes, i used it for dattables to show records etc, i am using it for first time, so that's why i am stuck here..so need help... i am just fed up... i have done all the tweaks i found, but no success..:(

Comment: Where does the above script (_allows cells to be used for multiple columns using colspan_) come from? The error is obviously related to the first javascript snippet, not the server side scripting itself.

Answer (score 8):

In case others are experiencing this issue, I found that this occurs if you do the following:

- Use server-side processing
- Specify a tfoot in your HTML
- Define a columns array in your DataTables Javascript setup that does not include one column definition for every cell in your tfoot

The solution is to make sure the columns definition in your Javascript matches the actual number of cells in your HTML.  This issue is still relevant with the new DataTables API.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem.  In Firebug the console shows: TypeError: column is undefined    column.nTf = cells[i].cell;   
I do have a tfoot in my table, which I kinda need. I suppose I could take it out and show it below the table...  Anyone know why it's happening though and the proper solution/.

Comment: Don't use a colspan in the tfoot, I don't think it will work.  Put as many cells in the tfoot as you do in the tbody, and make sure there are as many column definitions in your DataTable Javascript instantiation as there are in the tfoot.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't resolve the issue.  I need to put a colspan in the tfoot because I need to put something in there as wide as the combination of all the cells. This should work.

Answer (score 2):

Checking that tfoot columns number are such as in tbody.
Probably You have more columns in tfoot than in the tbody

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem twice and both times it was because I had more columns in my `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` than columns in the `<tbody>`.